# abs() returns a negative value for some very large double values

Tags: c++, absolute

I was working with some big double values and all mathematical functions were fine. It seems that sqrt, pow and other math functions don't have any problems with big scientific double values, but abs can't handle these numbers.
for example, this is ok:

```
double s = sqrt(3.9 * 1e32);
```

but this isn't:

```
double s = sqrt(abs(3.9 * 1e32));
```

because abs returns a negative value;
I don't understand why this simple function can't handle scientific double operations when all those complex ones are working fine. Am I missing  something or it's really this way and I can't use c++ abs function for such values?

### MCVE

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    double d = 3.9e32;
    double f = abs(d);

    std::printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

### Results

- [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/845ed498506b0d7c): `2147483647.000000`
- g++ 4.8.3-cygwin: `-2147483648.000000`

In this MCVE, changing `abs` to `std::abs` causes a compilation error due to overload resolution failure (can't choose between `std::abs<int>`, `std::abs<long>`, `std::abs<long long>`).

Comment: Works fine at http://ideone.com/6CkMVS

Comment: Yes John, the real code is valid. I just wrote it here and didn't copy the code.

Comment: You're right R Sahu, it's working fine there. But in my Qt project on Linux it's getting -nan

Comment: OK well I assure you that `abs()` never returns a negative number.  Perhaps you are casting it into an int or something.  You need to print out exactly what each part of  the expression contains at each step.  And always, always use `std::abs()` explicitly in C++, because `abs()` is dangerous: it returns `int`.

Comment: How is it being *verified* that the output of abs is a negative value?

Comment: Here is the code which is getting -nan in output

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double d = 3.9 * 1e32;
    double s = sqrt(abs(d));
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

Comment: @user2864740: I just assigned the return value of abs to a double variable. It was some negative value and by the way it's the only way that sqrt gives nan in output

Comment: @MSH: If you want to use `abs` and `sqrt`, you have to include `<math.h>`. If you want to include <cmath>, you have to use `std::abs` and `std::sqrt`. Either this or that. The code you posted in the comment is not even compilable.

Comment: @AndreyT You're completely right, it's because I am using Qt and it has probably included several other headers which leads to this situation.

Comment: he said *compilable*, not compatible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're using `abs(int)` when you need `fabs(double)` or better in C++, `std::abs()`.  You said you tried `std::abs()`, but if you had it would have fixed your problem.

This is an unfortunate and common trap in C++.  Never use `abs()` without `std::` on the front.  It's dangerous.

Comment: Wouldn't the selection of `abs(int)` result in a type error when `3.9 * 1e32` is applied as the argument?

Comment: Ok, you're right! thanks. but fabs is not working correctly here

Comment: Misleading answer. There's no need to use `fabs` in C++ code. Function `abs` is overloaded for all argument types, provided the proper header files are included.

Comment: @AndreyT: I did say "better in C++, std::abs()."  In case my English is not clear enough, that means "If you're using C++, always use `std::abs()`."

Comment: @user2864740 no, C++ has implicit conversion from double to int. (Which causes undefined behaviour if the double is greater than `INT_MAX`).

Comment: @John Zwinck: It might be a better idea to use `std::abs` from stylistic point of view, but the point is that it does not fix any problems at all. How could it? The set of overloaded `abs` functions is the same in global namespace and in `std` namespace.

Comment: @user2864740: It should result in overload resolution error, since the same header that declares `abs(int)` also declares `abs(long)` right next to it. A `double` argument does not match either, which triggers overload resolution error.

Answer (score 4):

The claim that `abs` return `int` in C++ mentioned in other answers is completely incorrect. In C++ standard library function `abs` is overloaded for different argument (and return) types. Header `<stdlib.h>` (or `<cstdlib>`) provides overloads for integral arguments. Header `<math.h>` (or `<cmath>`) provides overloads for floating-point arguments.

The question in this case is which header file the OP used in the program. If `<math.h>` was included, then `abs` should have called `double abs(double)` and generated a proper result (barring a broken compiler). If `<stdlib.h>` was included (and no `<math.h>`), then the call should have resulted in overload resolution failure due to availablity of both `abs(int)` and `abs(long)`.

This applies in equal degree to both `abs` and `std::abs`. Which one you should use depends only on what header files you include: `<stdlib.h>`-`<math.h>` or `<cstdlib>`-`<cmath>` respectively. Note that using `std::abs` instead of `abs` does not have any effect on this problem at all: the set of overloaded functions is the same in both cases.

If in the OP's case the `int` version of `abs` was called, it would be a quirk of the implementation. There's actually a DR that deals with this issue

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2380

Comment: I have added a MCVE to the original post, I guess either we have a lot of broken libraries around, or someone is overlooking something!

Comment: ISTR that it's unspecified whether a name from `std::` is injected into the global namespace also ; so perhaps it is permitted for an implementation to inject `int abs(int)` into global but not any others? (or something)

Comment: @Matt McNabb: Yes, but why are you calling `abs` (not `std::abs`) after including `<c..>` style headers? Formally, the code is not valid in general case. The rest is a quirk of implementation.

Comment: I'm doing `abs` to generate this problem of course! :)

Comment: well that explains OP's problem I think